# Trouble Reading from SD Card over SPI

Tags: arduino, sd-card

I have a project where I am using SPI to read from an SD card to load images onto an LCD screen. I am using an Arduino Zero (ATSAMD21). Everything was working until a couple days ago when, without hardware modification and without any (apparent) code modifications, the SD card no longer is detected.  The SPI still works because I can write data to the screen. However, it does not detect any signal from the SD card. When I try to initialize the SD card using the Arduino supplied SD library, I call `SD.begin(SD_CS);` using SD_CS for my chip select pin.
I went ahead and changed the following line in the 'begin' class in the SD library from:

```
return card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, csPin) &&
         volume.init(card) &&
         root.openRoot(volume);
```

to

```
if(!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, csPin)){
         return -1;
     }
     if(!volume.init(card)){
         return -2;
     }
     if(!root.openRoot(volume)){
         return -3;
     }
     return 0;
```

Then, when I run my code and try to open the SD card multiple times, I get:

```
Open SD: Err = -2 [Error initializing volume]
Open SD: Err = -1 [Error initializing card (timeout)]
Open SD: Err = -2 [Error initializing volume]
```

Keep in mind, I have a unit with the exact same setup that does not produce this error.
I've hooked it up to a logic analyzer as well. There is no CS mixup that would cause a bus collision (Image 1). And furthermore, I actually receive a return signal from the SD card! (Image 2)

[Full SPI bus transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvI15.png)

[SD Card sends return signal over SPI!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZWz6.png)

There is an anomaly that I am seeing on the analyzer that I am not familiar with. Referring to Image 3, there is a bit of clock data transmitted BEFORE the CS pin goes low. This is in the Sd2Card.cpp part of the SD library

```
// must supply min of 74 clock cycles with CS high.
#ifdef USE_SPI_LIB
  SDCARD_SPI.beginTransaction(settings);
#endif
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) spiSend(0XFF);
#ifdef USE_SPI_LIB
  SDCARD_SPI.endTransaction();
#endif
```

[Empty SPI CLK cycles before transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl7VD.png)

I've checked the continuity of the Chip Select pins. Also, as you can see from the logic analyzer, there is something being transmitted on both MOSI and MISO!

Is there something in my code I should look for while initializing the SD card? Why does it fail to read the files when I have been using the exact same SD.begin(SD_CS) function and had it work before? And why does it fail to see any signal on the MISO line, despite the fact that it is returning signals?

Thank you for taking the time to read this!